# Struct with integer or float

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and currently reading about structs. The code below is just a simple test of mine and I was wondering how to allow any numeric value as a property `r` of the Circle structure. I want it to be able to store an integer or a float.

I would assume overloading but not sure. Also from what I've searched online there are some crates `num` and `num-traits` but I'm unsure how to use them, unless I missed the doscs section.

```
use std::f64::consts::PI;

trait Area {
    fn calculate_area(self) -> f64;
}

struct Circle {
    r:f64
}

impl Area for Circle {
    fn calculate_area(self) -> f64 { 
        PI * self.r * self.r
    }
}

fn main() {

    let c = Circle { r: 2.5 };

    println!("The area is {}", c.calculate_area())
    
}
```

I would prefer a solution without having to include another crate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy using the `num_traits` crate:

```
use num_traits::{FromPrimitive, Num};
use std::f64::consts::PI;

trait Area<T>
where
    T: Num + FromPrimitive + Copy,
{
    fn calculate_area(self) -> T;
}

struct Circle<T>
where
    T: Num + FromPrimitive + Copy,
{
    r: T,
}

impl<T> Area<T> for Circle<T>
where
    T: Num + FromPrimitive + Copy,
{
    fn calculate_area(self) -> T {
        T::from_f64(PI).unwrap() * self.r * self.r
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Circle { r: 2.5 };

    println!("Float: The area is {}", c.calculate_area());

    let ci = Circle { r: 3 };

    println!("Integer: The (approxmiate) area is {}", ci.calculate_area());
}
```

Comment: I would even make `T` in `Arena<T>` an associated type: for any given type, you will ever have one implementation of `Arena`. Plus you can use the [`FloatConst`](https://docs.rs/num/0.3.1/num/traits/trait.FloatConst.html) trait to use directly `T::PI`.

Comment: The use of `T::from_f64(PI)` is somewhat dubious, since it may cause the result to be off by a  lot more than the precision of `T` (for instance, 9π is closer to 28 than 27). But it's not super clear what the "correct" behavior should be in this case, so *shrug*